# Is there a GTK terminal component that can be used under Windows?

Tags: windows, gtk

I need to build a terminal-like application that needs to be used under my usual Ubuntu install but also under Windows. I've been looking for a terminal component that accepts commands and is able to show some kind of command history together with output.

There is a component called VTE that is used in gnome-terminal, but I have not been able to compile it under Windows because it depends on some Unix-specific functions (as it seems). Do you know of any other terminal-like GTK components that can be built under Windows or some way to build VTE?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to look at the old GNOME widget called zvt, it might have been ported to Win32.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot wxt provides a terminal which is compiled with GTK on X and uses the win32 API on windows.  It uses the WxWindows interface to compile into both environments.

Answer (score 1):

No there still isn't, even years later.

Comment: By the way... I've started doing it at the time I wrote this question and actually got something working. I can try to respawn the code if anyone is interested.

Comment: @ThiagoArrais I am incredibly interested, would you be open to posting that code on Github per chance?